# How to create the design matrix for polynomial fitting when we have more than one independent variables?

Tags: c, matrix, numerical-methods, polynomials

So, I know how to create this matrix when I have one independent variable - the first column is x^0, second is x^1 and so on.

But now I have 5 independent variables in my source file. Where should I append these variables? To the design matrix as columns, starting with 1 again, or rows to the end? Any help appreciated, I feel lost.

Preview from the data file:

> 19.1711 17.6627 16.9633 16.6589 16.4254 0.075425 0.000735076
>   17.8339 16.0603 15.2756 14.9411 14.67 0.0473088 0.000123015
>   19.4924 17.7911 16.8446 16.3533 16.0243 0.075209 0.000393925
>   20.8318 19.0214 18.1391 17.6094 17.0731 0.131067 0.000252981
>   18.7056 16.6385 15.6452 15.2564 14.9338 0.131141 0.000217805

The first five columns are the independent variables, the sixth is the y, and the last one is the error.

According portion of my code:

```
int i, j, k;
for(i=0;i<(rows);i++)
{
  for(j=0;j<(pol+1);j++)
  {
    designm[(pol+1)*i+j] = 1;
    if(j==0)
      {
        continue;
      }
      else
        {
          for(k=0;k<j;k++)
        {
            designm[(pol+1)*i+j] *= mat[cols*i+0];
        }
      }
    }
}
```

What this does: I have the `mat` matrix, where I store everything I read from the source file. I have the `designm` where I store the design matrix. So far as you can see, I powered the first column of `mat` only, as I don't know where I should append the other four columns.

Comment: This is a math question, not a programming question. Try on the math stack exchanges instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about math and should be on http://math.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: I need to do this in C programming. Does that still count as math?

Comment: If you show some actual code and indicate where you are stuck, possibly with attempts, it may be a good StackOverflow question. For now, without even pseudo code, it doesn't seem to be an actual programming question.

Comment: alright then, I'm editing

Comment: I hope it's better this way

Comment: The bottom line is you create a solution-vector of independent variables (e.g. the `x^0, x^1, ...` leaving a coefficient matrix and you multiply by the inverse of your coefficient matrix (e.g. divide it) to determine the value of each associated independent variable (see "solving a linear-system of equations with matrix operations") (I would do 12x12 matrx divisions on my H28S back in the late 80's working on my engineering degree at A&M with its whopping 32k of memory. `:)`

Comment: I'm posting it to the math stackexchange as well, just in case.